# What exactly is being done in Prometheus Metrics (Histogram for example)

Tags: python, prometheus

I am having a hard time understanding Prometheus metrics and their meanings.

I have written this very simple python file

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Histogram
import random
import time


SOME_MEASURE= Histogram('some_measure_seconds', 'Some measure I am trying to graph')

list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


def register_histo(i):
    SOME_MEASURE.observe(i)
    time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    while True:
        for i in list:
            #print(i)
            register_histo(i)
```

As you can see I have a list with very clear numbers, 1,2,3,etc. and I am putting them in the Histogram (or at least that is what I expect)

Then I start prometheus and I query

`some_measure_seconds_count`

and I get

```
some_measure_seconds_count{instance="localhost:8000",job="example"}             9
```

Cool, I suppose that is the 9, right? but then I execute again and I get 20!!

Where is this 20 coming from. I am supposedly putting as metrics 1,2,3....10, not 20

So in conclusion I don't know what this Histogram metric is holding and I don't know how I can see clearly my 1,2,3....10 values.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to forgo Prometheus server for now and just look at the data that is returned when you query `localhost:8000` after every call to the `observe()` method. This way you will better understand how and why a histogram metric consists out of multiple time series.